# Pagedown Markdown editor : issue with images

Tags: css, markdown, pagedown

When using [PageDown](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/wiki/PageDown), there is some problem when inserting an image which is too big.

It is not redimensioned to a size that would fit in the editor's width (that would be possible with `<img src="" width="...">`)

Example : try to insert this image URL http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4b/Apple_pie.jpg in this editor :

http://www.markitdown.net/markdown.

**How to make image fit in the container with Markdown ?**
(this is done on StackOverflow's editor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with the Pagedown editor

http://pagedown.googlecode.com/hg/demo/browser/demo.html

it finally works by adding

```
#wmd-preview img { max-width: 500px; }
```

All images (even big ones) will have a max width of 500px.

Answer (score 1):

You can append =WIDTHxHEIGHT after the URL to resize the image. Do not forget the space before the =

```
![](./applePie.png =100x200)
```

Height is also optional so you can do...

```
![](./applePie.png =100x)
```

If you're referring to StackOverflow images, there's a good description here off what's possible: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#images

Comment: When we enter some `markdown` with `PageDown` editor, it creates :
`![enter image description here][1]` and `[1]: http://www.example.com/file.jpg`... I tried to modify the latter to `[1]: http://www.example.com/file.jpg =100x200` but it does not work.

Comment: Have a look at the link I supplied, in particular `You can also use standard HTML image syntax, which allows you to scale the width and height of the image.` Does not appear SO allows full markdown image syntax, if you want to control dimensions you need to use HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The only way which works with the editor you provide is this:

```
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4b/Apple_pie.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
```

Which render:

[image]

instead of:

[image]

But it's not in the markdown spirit...

Comment: @Basj I'm afraid markdown can't handle this. And by the way, SE sites wrap the markdown content to make it works

Comment: When using the Pagedown editor here http://www.markitdown.net/markdown, can we add some custom css to make that every embedded images will aways have max width of, say, 500px? How would this be possible @Thomas  ?

Comment: @Basj you mean, when you use *this* editor or you want to create/bundle your own ?

Comment: I mean with the Pagedown editor (linked in the question), here is a demo of it : http://pagedown.googlecode.com/hg/demo/browser/demo.html . I finally solved it following your advice (wrap the content). I'll award the bounty as soon as possible (23 hours remaining).

Comment: @Basj: `img {max-width:100%}` is a very common thing to find in CSS (don't let the image stick out of its surrounding container). You could use `500px` instead of `100%` and see where that leads you.